# How to create Tree View Layout in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making a screen when I need to show design like Screen Below, with tree views and connectors.
It will be a great help if someone can suggest me how to create a design like this, conceptually.
I have tried a [Gridview](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists) and [tree_view](https://pub.dev/packages/tree_view) so far.

```
GridView.count(
  // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
  // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
  children: List.generate(100, (index) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Item $index',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the public flutter package called [GraphView](https://pub.dev/packages/graphview)

> Flutter GraphView is used to display data in graph structures. It can
> display Tree layout, Directed and Layered graph. Useful for Family
> Tree, Hierarchy View.
>
> The library is designed to support different graph layouts and currently works excellent with small graphs.

Answer (score 1):

[graphite](https://pub.dev/packages/graphite) is somewhat similar to the design,

```
DirectGraph(
        list: list,
        cellWidth: 136.0,
        cellPadding: 24.0,
        orientation: MatrixOrientation.Vertical,
      )
```